# How do you remove/hide the ignore button code-push react-native?

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I am new to using code-push for react native app, Everything works okay however I want to hide the Ignore button in the dialog. I dont want the user to ignore any update I have provided, Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line, you can use the mandatory option to hide the ignore button:

```
# Release a mandatory update with a changelog
code-push release-react MyApp-iOS ios -m --description "Modified the header color"
```

Comment: Thanks @Nabil, I had no idea about that one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want user ignore the update, then don't show the dialog at all.

Just change **codePushOptions** so the user always get update when open the app from background in next time:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
} from 'react-native';

import codePush from "react-native-code-push";

let codePushOptions = {
    checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME,
    installMode: codePush.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESUME,
};

import App from './app/app';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('yourApp', () => codePush(codePushOptions)(App));
```

Comment: Thanks @Gray, This is also another option.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with it is not recommended to use UpdateDialog  within your application because the App could be rejected by AppStore at all due to [AppStore Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) states that

> Apps must not force users to rate the app, review the app, download
>   other apps, or other similar actions in order to access functionality,
>   content, or use of the app.

So use it with care and also please see [this reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/tree/v5.0.0-beta#store-guideline-compliance) for more details.

As for hiding `Ignore` button - you could do it providing an empty string instead of button name e.g. as follows:

`CodePush.sync(
      { installMode: CodePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE, updateDialog: { optionalIgnoreButtonLabel: "" } }, null, null );`

Answer (score 0):

you can also do  the same thing with the help of appcenter webview page .
you just only need to:
**go into the appcenter and indside your AppOverview>>Distribute>>CodePush:** .

click on setting icon and click ON on the update required btn.[image]